# Show a RTSP stream on Blazor wasm without re-streaming

Tags: video, blazor, rtsp, webassembly

on a Blazor PWA wasm I need to show to the user an RTSP stream (for example: rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mp4). I first thought this was possible using the html5 video tag, but it didn't work.

After reading a lot an try a lot of things, I can't do it without re-streaming the video on a backend, but in my situation I need to avoid that.

Can anyone help me or guide me how to achieve that?

Thanks.

Already try:

- html5 rtsp player: https://github.com/Streamedian/html5_rtsp_player (need a back to transform rtsp to websocket)
- FfmpegBlazor https://github.com/sps014/FFmpegBlazor (can't use a stream, only local files: https://github.com/sps014/FFmpegBlazor/issues/8)
- https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm (idem)
- Using csharp opencv to open stream and bind it to an image https://www.reddit.com/r/opencv/comments/gdueb9/question_correct_way_to_read_a_rtsp_stream_and/ + https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp + https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp_blazor_sample (can't open the video stream). Also [ASP.NET Core stream video from the OpenCVSharp capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57514490/asp-net-core-stream-video-from-the-opencvsharp-capture)
- C# RTSP Client for .NET Core 3.0 / .NET 5.0 https://github.com/i-TechSoftware/RtspClientSharpCore (need backend to re-stream)
- Stream API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API https://web.dev/media-mse-basics/ can't do it using rtsp strem
- On SO:

  - [How to stream video over rtsp protocol for Live555 server on web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233677/how-to-stream-video-over-rtsp-protocol-for-live555-server-on-web-browser/33497580#33497580)
  - [stream RTSP to HTML website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42598475/stream-rtsp-to-html-website)
  - [How can I display an RTSP video stream in a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245040/how-can-i-display-an-rtsp-video-stream-in-a-web-page)
  - [streaming rtsp video in vlc plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41490556/streaming-rtsp-video-in-vlc-plugin)
  - [RTSP to WEBRTC live video streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61672575/rtsp-to-webrtc-live-video-streaming)
  - [RTSP h.264 in google chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41965793/rtsp-h-264-in-google-chrome-browser)
  - [Realtime WebSocket stream to RTSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70104805/realtime-websocket-stream-to-rtsp)
  - [Best approach to get RTSP streaming into web browser from IP Camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011302/best-approach-to-get-rtsp-streaming-into-web-browser-from-ip-camera)
  - [Forwarding RTSP stream from IP Camera to Browser in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69899709/forwarding-rtsp-stream-from-ip-camera-to-browser-in-asp-net-core)
  - [live stream RTSP to html all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62304488/live-stream-rtsp-to-html-all-browsers)
  - [How to embed streaming rtsp media into an html5 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48588485/how-to-embed-streaming-rtsp-media-into-an-html5-page)
  - [OpenCV videocapture read camera rtsp error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65574163/opencv-videocapture-read-camera-rtsp-error)
  - [Streaming via RTSP or RTP in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5)
  - [RTSP solution for JavaScript/HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440265/rtsp-solution-for-javascript-html5)
  - [RTP RTSP implementation in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887877/rtp-rtsp-implementation-in-javascript)
  - [Streaming via RTSP or RTP in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5)
  - [Is it possible to send RTSP streaming to html page using node js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927507/is-it-possible-to-send-rtsp-streaming-to-html-page-using-node-js)
  - [How to stream RTSP live video in Firefox and Chrome now that the VLC plugin is not supported anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080899/how-to-stream-rtsp-live-video-in-firefox-and-chrome-now-that-the-vlc-plugin-is-n)
  - [How to stream video over rtsp protocol for Live555 server on web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233677/how-to-stream-video-over-rtsp-protocol-for-live555-server-on-web-browser)

Comment: Welcome to 2022, playing a nativ RTSP stream across Modern Browser is not possible yet. One direction is to use WebRtc but there u also need a service that handle the signaling etc. Other way is to use MSE but there u need to translate the stream into a fragmented mp4 stream. As you already described you need to have a transcoder or a similar service that do the work for u

Comment: Did you solve this ? Having the exact same problem. Any update for this in 2023? @Christoph

Comment: Hi @ArturM, sadly no :(
We are re-streaming the video to get it working

Comment: Thank you for the reply! So you stream RTSP to the backend (which lib are you using for this?) and then you stream to frontend via WebSocket? If this is accurate which libs are you using for WebSocket Server/Client. Any examples for this?

Comment: yeah, but most of the code is hand made, give me a day to go back to that project and answer property

Comment: @ArturM, to connect and receive video streams we use FFMpegCore, for restreaming we use System.Net.WebSockets directly.

We have it separated like this:
**(A) -** A controller (API) [1] that has a method to start the stream from an RTSP server, which receives a connection string.
**(B) -** A service consumed by [1] that allows starting a websocket that clients would connect to.
**(C) -** These clients connect to the websocket and start receiving the bytes. For this we use jsmpeg to receive and docode the bytes.